How to solve: Compile error variable not defined?
I am creating duty rosters for my team in excel. The method is that let's say a whole year is a workbook anf each month is on a separete worksheet. Until now I used the excel given conditional formatting but I had to redo it again and again for each month/sheet. At list I colud not figure out how to simply copy them to a new sheet. Therefore; I am trying now to create a simple WBA code which works for the whole workbook, every sheet. I would like to have certain cells filled with defined colors when a certain letter or number is written in the cell.
I made this code but now running into the problem, described in the title. Would you please have a look in my code, which I paste below and help me to solve it or tell me if you see any other mistakes in it:
Option Explicit

Sub EasyColors()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    With wb
        lrow = .Range(("C:AG") & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                
        Set rng = .Range("C7:AG41")
    End With

    With rng
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xl.Equals, Formula1:="D"
        .FormatConditions.Add .Interior.Color = RGB(180, 198, 231)
    End With

End Sub


Please [edit] the question and add the full error, with stack-trace (as text) inside it

Range is a property of a worksheet not a workbook.

I've run stack-trace, nothing happened. However I found this with Debug quick-watch: Watch :   : xl : <Can't compile module> : Empty : ThisWorkbook.EasyColors

Dear SJR, Thanks for that, will keep it mind. I used workbook because I would like to have it working also when I create a new sheet as a new monthly roster. Maybe not the way though.

Have a look to then documentation of FormatConditions.Add: The parameter Operator must be one one the values listed here.
You simply have a typo at the constant. You write Operator:=xl.Equals, but it must be Operator:=xlEqual.
If you use Debug->Compile, the VBA editor will jump directly to the invalid value.

Update I was only focusing on the compile error you got concerning the undefined variables. Having a close look to your code, I found three four more issues:
(1) A range is always part of a sheet, not a workbook - stated in the comments by SJR. Change the line to something like this (and select the sheet you want to work with):
With wb.Sheets(1)

(2) It must be .Range(("C1:AG") & .Rows.Count), else the range definition is wrong
(3) You figure out the last row, but you don't use it. Probably it should be something like this:
Set rng = .Range("C7:AG" & lRow)

(4) After adding the FormatCondition, you want to set the background color for that newly added condition, but you are calling the Add-method a 2nd time. This is not what you want plus it's an invalid syntax.
So your code could look like this
Sub EasyColors()
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        lrow = .Range(("C1:AG") & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        Set rng = .Range("C7:AG" & lRow)
    End With

    With rng.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="D")
        .Interior.Color = RGB(180, 198, 231)
    End With    
End Sub


Dear FunThomas, changed the operator, now I get this: "Run-time error: 438, Object does not support proberty or method." Sub EasyColors() highlighted

@TiborBalogh  See my update

Dear FunThomas, Your code was working but only for the C column. However, I removed the last row and just simply changed the cell range to C7:AG40 and now it seems to be working and still worked when I inserted the second worksheet. Thank you very much for your help, it is much appreciated and was good to lower my blood pressure.
